# osx open Proxies tab in network preferences programmatically

Tags: python, macos

How can I programmatically open the 'Proxies' tab in 'Network' dialog box?
System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies

For those using Chrome, if you go to Menu > Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Change proxy settings... , the 'Network' box shows up, and its already on the 'Proxies' tab.

I want to achieve this using python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is through Apple Events. If you open AppleScript Editor, you can Open Dictionary on System Preferences and see the commands:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane "com.apple.preference.network"
end tell
```

So, how do you do this from Python? There are three options:

1. Create some AppleScript and run it via PyObjC, or via a wrapper like [py-applescript](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-applescript).
2. Use [ScriptingBridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/UsingScriptingBridge.html), Apple's AppleEvents-to-Python (and -Ruby and -ObjC) bridge.
3. Use [appscript](https://github.com/abarnert/appscript), a third-party AppleEvents-to-Python (and …) bridge.

Appscript is a lot better, but it's effectively an abandoned project, and ScriptingBridge comes with Apple's version of Python. So, I'll show that first:

```
import ScriptingBridge
sp = ScriptingBridge.SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_('com.apple.SystemPreferences')
panes = sp.panes()
pane = panes.objectWithName_('com.apple.preference.network')
anchors = pane.anchors()
dummy_anchor = anchors.objectAtIndex_(0)
dummy_anchor.reveal()
```

You may notice that the ScriptingBridge version is a lot more verbose and annoying than the AppleScript. There are a few reasons for this.

1. ScriptingBridge isn't really an AppleEvent-Python bridge, it's an AppleEvent-ObjC bridge wrapped up in PyObjC, so you have to use horribleObjectiveCSyntax_withUnderscores_forEachParameterNamed_.
2. It's inherently horribly verbose.
3. The "obsolete" method of looking applications up by name isn't exposed in ScriptingBridge, so you have to find the bundle ID (or file:// URL) of the app and open that.
4. Most importantly, ScriptingBridge doesn't expose the actual object model; it forces it into a CocoaScripting OO-style model and exposes that. So, while System Preferences knows how to `reveal` anything, the ScriptingBridge wrapper only knows how to call the `reveal` method on an `anchor` object.

While the last two are the most troublesome, the first two can be annoying as well. For example, even using bundle IDs and following the CocoaScripting model, here's what the equivalent looks like in AppleScript:

```
tell application "com.apple.SystemPreferences"
    reveal first anchor of pane "com.apple.preference.network"
end tell
```

… and in Python with `appscript`:

```
import appscript
sp = appscript.app('com.apple.SystemPreferences')
sp.panes['com.apple.preference.network'].anchors[1].reveal()
```

---

Meanwhile, in general, I wouldn't recommend any Python programmer move any of their logic into AppleScript, or try to write logic that crosses the boundaries (because I subscribe to the Geneva conventions against torture). So, I immediately start with ScriptingBridge or appscript in any case where we might need so much as an `if` statement. But in this case, as it turns out, we don't need that. So, using an AppleScript solution might be the best answer. Here's the code with py-applescript, or with nothing but what Apple gives you out of the box:

```
import applescript
scpt = 'tell app "System Preferences" to reveal pane "com.apple.preference.network"'
applescript.AppleScript(scpt).run()

import Foundation
scpt = 'tell app "System Preferences" to reveal pane "com.apple.preference.network"'
ascpt = Foundation.NSAppleScript.alloc()
ascpt.initWithSource_(scpt)
ascpt.executeAndReturnError_(None)
```

Comment: Using ScriptingBridge, how do I get to Network > Advanced > Proxies?

Comment: @mingxiao: You need to use the name of the anchor, instead of just specifying the first anchor in the pane. Rather than do it for you, I'll explain how to figure it out: In your interactive Python interpreter (or in AppleScript editor, if AS doesn't make your head asplode), print out the names of all of the anchors with `[anchor.name() for anchor in pane.anchors()]`. Find the one you want. Then, instead of `anchors.objectWithID_(0)`, you'll use `anchors.objectWithName_("the name you found")`.

Comment: @abarnet: Another option is to use py-appscript to call AppleScript handlers from Python (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-applescript). It uses Apple-supported Cocoa APIs only so will hopefully survive a bit longer than appscript, and unlike osascript, which only understands strings, py-applescript can convert between most common Python and AppleScript types (booleans, numbers, strings, dates, lists, records, etc).

Comment: @foo: You didn't mean `py-appscript` there, did you? Because that's just the Python version of `appscript`, which is completely different from `py-applescript`. Anyway, I think using `py-applescript` falls under running some AppleScript via PyObjC, but it does look like a nicer way to do it than calling the C or ObjC functions directly.

Comment: @foo: Anyway, the problem with using AppleScript either way is that you have to move some of your logic from Python into AppleScript, and if you wanted to be coding logic in AppleScript, you wouldn't be using Python because your mental hospital wouldn't allow it. But in this use case, where all you want to do is `tell app "System Preferences" to reveal anchor "Proxies" of pane "com.apple.preference.network"` it seems like a good solution, so I'll edit the answer.